# Excel Macro for Exporting/CopyPaste to separate workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

Requesting some help from you more advanced excel VBA wizards.

Situation: I work as a medical administrator of sorts. HIPPA is obviously a concern for me as my personal tracker does contain a lot of HIPPA, and the whole "need to know" bit is a big deal. I need to have a workbook available for my subordinate staff to see without violating HIPPA

I have a workbook with a lot of data. I would like a separate workbook (Book2) to pull names from column A(the patients unit) and B(their name) if they meet a number or text condition from a separate column (let's call it column D).

I know I can filter, then copy/paste the list or data that is needed for them, but that is time consuming for 5 separate units with 100+ patients each. If at all possible, I would prefer to share Book2 with the option for them to leave comments next to the name. The idea is to just update BookA, so the can have the most up to date names in real time.

I've tried VBAs and customizing them to my criteria , but cant seem to find anything that works. Any help is appreciated.

*OP note - I'm still very much a novice at this whole macro thing. I'm not to the point of writing any code of my own yet, just stealing other people efforts. Which has been done successfully in previous needs.

Comment: Please provide the vba code you have tried and the problem/error your are experiencing. This will help others identify where you are having difficulties in your macro, and provide you with possible solutions to fixing your macro.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should get you started (Run from Book2);

```
Sub CopyIfCriteria()
    'Get other workbook and worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Excel.Workbooks("BookA.xlsx")

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'Column 1 = A
    Dim unit As Long
    unit = 1

    'Column 2 = B
    Dim name As Long
    name = 2

    'Column 4 = D
    Dim criteria As Long
    criteria = 4

    'Row 1 = 1, change if headers
    Dim firstRow As Long
    firstRow = 1

    'Row n = last row with data
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Current row index on BookA, starts at first row
    Dim copyIndex As Long
    copyIndex = firstRow

    'Current row index on Book2, starts at row 1
    Dim pasteIndex As Long
    pasteIndex = 1

    For copyIndex = firstRow To lastRow
        'Change what the condition is to check if criteria is correct
        If (CBool(ws.Cells(copyIndex, criteria).Value) = True) Then
            'Copy unit and name to the next available row on Book2; pasteIndex
            ws.Cells(copyIndex, unit).Copy Cells(pasteIndex, unit)
            ws.Cells(copyIndex, name).Copy Cells(pasteIndex, name)

            'Use pasteIndex to find what row we're up to on Book2, increment everytime we use a row
            pasteIndex = pasteIndex + 1
        End If
    Next copyIndex
End Sub
```

This will simply get the BookA workbook, assuming it is opened in Excel, and then iterate through every row. If column D (4) has the correct criteria, then it'll copy column 1 and 2 (A & B) of that row to the next un-used row in Book2.

You will ned to have a blank Excel file (from which the code is run) open, as well as having BookA open (and having the data on Sheet1) of BookA. If they're not in 'BookA.xlsx' or 'Sheet1' then simply change the names to suit your needs.

Do take the time to just read through it and take not of the comments to help you understand better how it is doing it.